# How do I create shy groups in Emacs with rx?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Generally, I can use the excellent `rx` macro to create readable regular expressions and be sure that I've escaped the correct metacharacters.

```
(rx (any "A-Z")) ;; "[A-Z]"
```

However, I can't work out how to create shy groups, e.g. `\(?:AB\)`. `rx` sometimes produces them in its output:

```
(rx (or "ab" "bc")) ;; "\\(?:ab\\|bc\\)"
```

but I want to explicitly add them. I can do:

```
(rx (regexp "\\(?:AB\\)"))
```

but this defeats the point of `rx`.

In a perfect world, I'd like to be able to write:

```
(rx (shy-group "A"))
```

I'd settle for something like this (none of these work):

```
;; sadly, `regexp` only accepts literal strings
(rx (regexp (format "\\(?:%s\\)" (rx WHATEVER))))

;; also unfortunate, `eval` quotes the string it's given
(rx (eval (format "\\(?:%s\\)" (rx WHATEVER))))
```

How can I create regular expressions with shy groups using `rx`?

Comment: Isn't the idea that the structure of a `rx` form makes explicit shy groups redundant? In which situation do you need this?

Comment: Oh, that didn't occur to me. I wanted it when I wanted to rewrite some string regular expressions to use `rx`. Is it always possible to rewrite an arbitrary regex in `rx` without explicit shy groups? (You're also basically answering the question, so would you like to submit an answer?)

Comment: Based on the library commentary which states "Rx completely covers all regexp features", I believe this should be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the structure of a `rx` form eliminates any need to explicitly create shy groups -- everything that a shy group could be needed for is accounted for by other syntax.

e.g. your own example:

```el
(rx (or "ab" "bc")) ;; "\\(?:ab\\|bc\\)"
```

Answer (score 2):

For other cases, it is also possible to [extend the keywords used by rx](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/rx).

Example (taken from EmacsWiki link above):

```
(defmacro rx-extra (&rest body-forms)
   (let ((add-ins (list
                   `(file . ,(rx (+ (or alnum digit "." "/" "-" "_"))))
                   `(ws0 . ,(rx (0+ (any " " "\t"))))
                   `(ws+ . ,(rx (+ (any " " "\t"))))
                   `(int . ,(rx (+ digit))))))
     `(let ((rx-constituents (append ',add-ins rx-constituents nil)))
        ,@body-forms)))
```